# How to get all the urls that contain specific string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to get all the urls that end with ".jpg". My code:

```
func findPicUrl(url: NSURL){
    var error: NSError?
    var HTML = NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
    var detector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, error: nil)
    var matches = detector!.matchesInString(HTML! as String, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, HTML!.length))
    for match in matches {
        if (match as! NSString).containsString(".jpg"){
            println(match)
        }
    }
}
```

It prints all the urls without "*if statement*" but when i add "*if statement*" i get an error

> "Could not cast value of type 'NSLinkCheckingResult' to 'NSString'"**.

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to double unwrap the `URL` property from the `NSLinkCheckingResult`s, cast it as an NSURL then you can use the `pathExtension` property to find "jpg" images links:

```
for match in matches {
    if let temp = match.URL, matchURL = temp as NSURL! {
        if matchURL.pathExtension == "jpg" {
            println(matchURL.absoluteString!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `pathExtension` is perfect. +1

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop code as below.

```
   for match in matches {
        if match.rangeOfString(".jpg") != nil{
           println("match")
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation  says:

*NSTextCheckingResult is a class used to describe items located by text checking. Each of these objects represents an occurrence of requested textual content that has been found during the analysis of a block of text.*

For example NSTextCheckingResult has a `range` property which contains the range of the matching string in the `HTML` variable.

Try this

```
var error: NSError?
if let HTML = NSString(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"http://macfix.de")!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
  let detector = NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue, error: nil)
  let matches = detector!.matchesInString(HTML as String, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, HTML.length))
  for match in matches {
    let HTMLmatch = (HTML as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range)
    if HTMLmatch.rangeOfString("jpg") != nil {
      println(HTMLmatch)
    }
  }
}
```